# SpringMVC controller: how to stay on page if form validation error occurs

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have next working code in my *SpringMVC* controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void registerForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("registerInfo", new UserRegistrationForm());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/reg", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("registerInfo") UserRegistrationForm userRegistrationForm,
        BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "register";
    }
    userService.addUser(userRegistrationForm);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

In short `create` method try to validate `UserRegistrationForm`. If form has errors, it leaves user on the same page with filled form fields where error message will be shown.

Now I need to apply the same behaviour to another page, but here I have a problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buy/{buyId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String buyGet(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, @PathVariable long buyId) {
    model.addAttribute("buyForm", new BuyForm());
    return "/buy";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/buy/{buyId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String buyPost(@PathVariable long buyId,
                          @Valid @ModelAttribute("buyForm") BuyForm buyForm,
                          BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "/buy/" + buyId;
    }

    buyForm.setId(buyId);
    buyService.buy(buyForm);
    return "redirect:/show/" + buyId;
}
```

I faced with issue of dynamic url. Now if form has errors I should specify the same page template to stay on current page, but also I should pass `buyId` as a path variable. Where are a conflict in this two requirements. If I leave this code as is, I get an error (I'm using *Thymeleaf* as a template processor):

```
Error resolving template "/buy/3", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I can write something like `return "redirect:/buy/" + buyId`, but in this case I lose all data and errors of form object.

What should I do to implement in `buyPost` method the same behaviour as in `create` method?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039064/spring-mvc-prg-passing-values-to-other-operation/18039981#18039981, you could use FlashAttributes to pass data to the redirected view.

Comment: This solution is better than just redirect, because values of form's fields are saved. But in this case I loose my `BindingResult` for this form, so I still can't show validation errors to user after form submit.

Comment: You could pass BindingResult along with other data, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors

Comment: Thanks, now it's works. Previously I tried to pass `BindingResult` object using `FlashAttributes`, but I can't get it in my `buyGet` method through `@ModelAttribute` because `BindingResult` doesn't contains default constructor and can't be instantiated. So I passed this object through session, what's looks a little tricky.

Comment: Hippoom, you could format your comments as an answer and I'll accept it as a correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the solution metioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543797/spring-redirect-after-post-even-with-validation-errors) at this weekend, but it doesn't work for BindingResult.

The code below works but not perfect.

```
@ModelAttribute("command")
public PlaceOrderCommand command() {
    return new PlaceOrderCommand();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/placeOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String placeOrder(
        @ModelAttribute("command") PlaceOrderCommand command,
        ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.put(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "command",
            modelMap.get("errors"));
    return "placeOrder";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/placeOrder", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String placeOrder(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("command") PlaceOrderCommand command,
        final BindingResult bindingResult, Model model,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errors", bindingResult);

        //it doesn't work when passing this          
        //redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "command", bindingResult);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("command", command);
        return "redirect:/booking/placeOrder";
    }
    ......
}
```

Comment: Passing `BindingResult` through `addFlashAttribute` looks like common issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903238/passing-bindingresult-through-redirectionattributes
Anyway work-around was found, so the question could be closed. Thanks.

Comment: Mentioned solution didn't work for me too until I changed register in "org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.register" to the modelAttribute's name.

Answer (score 2):

*I'm using [Hibernate Validator APIs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/) to validate my beans. To preserve form data along with displaying error messages, you need to do these 3 things:

1. Annotate your bean (eg. @NotEmpty, @Pattern, @Length, @Email etc.)

[image]

2. Inside controller:

   @Controller
   public class RegistrationController {

   ```
   @Autowired
   private RegistrationService registrationService;

   @RequestMapping(value="register.htm", method=RequestMethod.GET, params="new")
   public String showRegistrationForm(Model model) {
       if (!model.containsAttribute("employee")) {
           model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
       }
       return "form/registration";
   }

   @RequestMapping(value="register.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.employee", bindingResult);
           redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("employee", employee);
           return "redirect:register.htm?new";
       }
       registrationService.save(employee);
       return "workspace";
   }
   // ....
   ```

   }
3. Update your view/jsp to hold error messages:

[image]

This [article](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/07/11/preserving-validation-error-messages-on-spring-mvc-form-post-redirect-get/*) can surely be helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change your POST implementation to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/buy/{buyId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String buyPost(@PathVariable long buyId,
                          @Valid @ModelAttribute("buyForm") BuyForm buyForm,
                          BindingResult result) {

    buyForm.setId(buyId); // important to do this also in the error case, otherwise, 
                          // if the validation fails multiple times it will not work.

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        byForm.setId(buyId);
        return "/buy/{buyId}";
    }

    buyService.buy(buyForm);
    return "redirect:/show/{buyId}";
}
```

Optionally, you can also annotate the method with `@PostMapping("/buy/{buyId}")` if you use Spring 4.3 or higher.